# Alamofire Error in Swift

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am making API calls to a server.

Please help me. My code is giving errors and not POSTing my data.

Here's my function that should hold details about the response :

```
@IBAction func registerButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let ss:String! = "client"
    let parameters:[String:String] = [
        "name"     : nameTextField.text!,
        "number"   : numberTextField.text!,
        "password" : passwordTextField.text!,
        "email"    : loginTextField.text!,
        "category" : ss!
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, myUrl, parameters:parameters, encoding : .JSON).responseJSON {
        response in
        print(response.request)  // original URL request
        print(response.response) // URL response
        print(response.data)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Or at least: what error do you get? I see a missing parameter name (before myUrl)  in the `request` method.

Comment: `My code is giving errors` This is not enough. We need to know *what are these errors*.

Comment: i am have registracia mtUrl

Comment: Is this error taking place during runtime or compile time?

Comment: yes.  not requerid my data